# Extract part of html with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

on alerting of these

```
var htmldata = theParent.html();
```

i have getting this result

```
<!--<div id="megamenu_part2">
    <div class="first_rowtitle" id="megamenu_part2-in"><h6><a href="/news/159">one is</a></h6>
    <div class="mochu_newstile">
        <span><img src="images/megamenu-icon_01.png"></span><span class="viewnumber_countfirst2">250</span>
        <span><img src="images/megamenu-icon_line.png"></span>
        <span><img src="megamenu-icon_comment.png"></span><span>0</span>
    </div>    
</div>-->
```

after that with the use of jQuery i want to get html() of class = 'viewnumber_countfirst2' how can i get ??
    is  `var childht    =  $(htmldata).$('.viewnumber_count_sh').html()` this will work????

Comment: there is not class `viewnumber_count_sh`

Comment: Maybe you should start by learning jQuery http://api.jquery.com

Comment: the class is 'viewnumber_countfirst2'

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var result = []
var htmldata = theParent.contents(); // return every DOM element inside theParent, including text and comment
htmldata.each(function(){
  // for each node, text and comment inside theParent
  current_content = $(this)
  if (current_content.nodeType == 8)
  {
    // if the current content is an html comment
    current_content.find('.viewnumber_countfirst2').each(function(){
      // for event inner node of the desired class: store its html
      result.append($(this).html());
    });
  }
});
```